# Date comparison and showing a list of unique dates from controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a list of dates that I want to compare with another set of dates (which I got using JS).

Given the range;

```
Start Date: 11/1/2017 12:00:00 AM
End Date: 11/20/2017 12:00:00 AM
```

Using the query;

```
var mod = (from m in lst
                              where m.RId == EN &&  m.Date >= startDate && m.Date <= endDate
                              select m).Distinct();
                   var earlyMod = mod
                    .GroupBy(dt => dt.Date)
                    .Select(z => z.OrderBy(y => y.Date).First())
                    .ToList();
                    var presRowCount = 0; //to get the count


                    presRowCount = earlyMod.Count();
                    ViewBag.presRowCount = presRowCount;
                        return View(earlyMod);
```

In the View;

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
<td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RegisterationId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateTime)
                @ViewBag.Dates
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </td> 
....}
```

What I get in the View is (Let's call it `presentDates`);

```
11/9/2017 8:02:09 AM    
11/10/2017 11:23:04 AM  
11/14/2017 10:11:11 AM
```

What I also have in the view is this JS function which has another set of dates (excluding weekends);

```
<script>
var startDate = '@ViewBag.StartDate';
    var endDate = '@ViewBag.EndDate';

    startDate = new Date(startDate);
    endDate = new Date(endDate);
var weekDay = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
    while (startDate <= endDate) {

        var new_weekDay = startDate.getDay();

        if (new_weekDay < 6 && new_weekDay > 0) {

            var month = startDate.getMonth() + 1;

            if (month <= 9) { month = "0" + month; }
            var day = startDate.getDate();
            if (day <= 9) { day = "0" + day; }
            document.write(day + "/" + month + "/" + startDate.getFullYear() + " (" + weekDay[new_weekDay] + ")<br />");
            console.log(day + "/" + month + "/" + startDate.getFullYear() + " (" + weekDay[new_weekDay] + ")<br />");
        }
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1)
```

What I get from the above JS function (Let's call it `weekDates`);

```
01/11/2017 (Wednesday)
02/11/2017 (Thursday)
03/11/2017 (Friday)
06/11/2017 (Monday)
07/11/2017 (Tuesday)
08/11/2017 (Wednesday)
09/11/2017 (Thursday)
10/11/2017 (Friday)
13/11/2017 (Monday)
14/11/2017 (Tuesday)
15/11/2017 (Wednesday)
```

What I want is a way to compare both the set of dates and display only the dates which are NOT present in both the sets (Let's call it `absentDates = weekDates - presentDates`);

```
01/11/2017 (Wednesday)
02/11/2017 (Thursday)
03/11/2017 (Friday)
06/11/2017 (Monday)
07/11/2017 (Tuesday)
08/11/2017 (Wednesday)
13/11/2017 (Monday)
```

Note: the format of the date is also different.

Comment: Where is this _set of javascript dates_ coming from? The fact you ave used `'@ViewBag.StartDate';` suggests its passed to from the controller theat generated your view, in which case why are you using javascript at all - you should be just doing the comparison in the controller and passing the correct data to the view in the first place

Comment: Hint: You can use `Except` method to exclude subset list items which exist in parent list. Which query you want to change/add with that filter?

Comment: @StephenMuecke that's right, I am fetching the start/end dates from controller since those dates are being fetched from a previous View (Index). If there is way to use the JS function in the controller and compare it with the already present list in controller (parent) and then pass the `absentDates` to the view. it would be great!

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I just want the `absentDates` shown, any way would work. Thank you :)

Comment: If your controller method is receiving a `StartDate` and `EndDate`, then you can using a simple loop to generate a List<DateTime> of all weekdays between those 2 dates (you can test the `DayOfWeek` property) and then use a linq `.Except()` clause to exclude the dates in your other query so that you pass just the data you want to the view (no javascript required)

Comment: @StephenMuecke that would be nice too but Im still learning so it's hard to implement what you mentioned. A solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: @StephenMuecke The controller method is receiving them like `public ActionResult Logs(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int EnrollNumber)
        {`

Comment: Your view shows a loop displaying properties for `RegisterationId`, `DateTime` and `Date` and it also contains `@ViewBag.Dates` (which you did not show the controller code for) so I'm a bit confused which property your displaying when you have said _What I get in the View is_

Comment: @StephenMuecke all those properties shown `RegisterationId, DateTime and Date` are being displayed fine. what I get in the View is a table that shows all the properties mentioned in the beginning of this comment. but I wish to change the date only and display the `absentDates` as mentioned in the question.

Comment: But where do you want to display the 'absent dates' - in a separate table after that `foreach` loop?

Comment: @StephenMuecke if we do not want to show the `presentDates` and only the `absentDates`, then yes, inside the `foreach` loop. Otherwise a separate table that will display the new `absentDates` and also the old list showing the `presentDates`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke let's say we do not want a separate table and display the 'absent dates' within the same `foreach` loop using the start and end dates to calculate the weekdays and then also the 'absent dates' inside the controller. this would work too!

Comment: Yes you could do that, but that would be just repeating the 'absent dates` in each iteration - if you have 10 items in your model then you would be repeating that list of absent dates 10 times

Comment: @StephenMuecke Obviously, we dont want a repeated date. I want the 'absent dates' filtered out as I tried to explain in my question. its fine even if we have to make a new table but no repetition.

Comment: I'm about to take a break for 30 min, but then will add an answer showing how to do this in the controller

Comment: @StephenMuecke Perfect, until then I will give this a try! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller is responsible for sending the correct data to thew view, so your should be building your list of 'absent' dates in the controller, not in javascript.

Build a list of weekdays between your `startDate` and `endDate` and then use a linq `.Except()` clause to exclude the dates that are included in your current query

```
// Build list of weekdays
List<DateTime> weekDays = new List<DateTime>();
int days = (endDate - startDate).Days;
for(int i = 0; i < days; i++)
{
    DateTime date = startDate.AddDays(i);
    if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        continue;
    }
    weekDays.Add(date);
}
// Get the dates to be excluded
IEnumerable<DateTime> excluded = earlyMod.Select(x => x.Date);
// Get the absent dates
IEnumerable<DateTime> absentDates = weekDays.Except(excluded);
```

Ideally you should be using a view model containing a property for the objects your current query returns, and a `IEnumerable<DateTime> AbsentDates` property, and pass that to the view so that its strongly typed (and get rid of all your `ViewBag` properties), but you could then pass it to the view using

```
ViewBag.AbsentDates = absentDates;
```

and use a `foreach` loop in the view to display them.

Note if you want a specific display format, then you could use `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy (dddd)")`

Comment: I tried to something similar, however this gives the following errs: for the last two lines, `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.DateTime?>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.DateTime>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` and  `'List<DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Exclude' and no extension method 'Exclude' accepting a first argument of type 'List<DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: The first error is resolved by changing it to `IEnumerable<DateTime?> excluded = earlyMod.Select(x => x.Date);` however the `Exclude` method error is still there.

Comment: You did not show your model, but that suggest your property is `DateTime?` (nullable). If that is the case, then its `earlyMod.Select(x => x.Date.Value);`

Comment: Oops - sorry its `.Except()`

Comment: I tried it with `Except()` and it worked. How do I pass/display all the absentDates to the view using `foreach`? definitely not like `return View(absentDates);`

Comment: As I noted, you really should be using a view model, but you can use `ViewBag.AbsentDates = absentDates;` and then in the view `@foreach(var date in ViewBag.AbsentDates) { @date }`

Comment: this works but what If I add its property to the model (as shown in the updated) question, but this would add another column named AbsentDates what If I want it to show in the `DateTime` in the same column according to the dates, i.e. all the presentDates shown and the absentDates according to the dates, then? also `Status` is used to denot either Absent or Present. THANK YOU!

Comment: First of all, do not modify your data model. You need to use view models to represent the data you want to display in the view. And I don't understand how you want to display this. Can you show an image of what you want the view to look like.

Comment: What I want is the absent dates to be shown in the same column (original view) according to the dates. just the status should be different. i.e. Absent for all the absent dates

Comment: I still do not understand how you want to modify the original table in your first image. Do you want to show all the dates in the table, and have the original rows marked 'Present' in the last column and rows for each of the other dates where its marked 'Absent' in the last column

Comment: I have added one record for the clarification: https://s17.postimg.org/900jvnixr/dem.png since 11/11/2017 and 11/12/2017 were weekends so theyre excluded and the absent date is inserted

Comment: So (just to clarify), you want one table row for each date between the `startDate` and `endDate`(except weekend dates) and if its one of the dates in your original `earlyMod` query then its marked 'Present' and if its one of the dates in the `absentDates`, then its marked `Absent'?

Comment: Exactly!  YES! :D

Comment: That is easy enough - but involves modifying your controller code, and using a view model. This thread is already getting to long, and I have answered the question, so ask a new question, including the code you currently have plus the code in my answer, plus your model, and then include a description of how you want to display it in the view (adding the images would probably help)

Comment: As a side note, why do you have 3 columns for the date - one for DateTime, one for Date and one for Time?

Comment: I would definitely do that then. Thank you :)

Comment: Please see this :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47468891/populating-linq-list-to-calendar-with-checkmarks-on-the-appropriate-dates

Comment: @Mogambo, Unfortunately I have not used fullcalendar-scheduler so probably cant help with that.

Comment: Ah, that's bad luck. Do you know anyway I can achieve what I am trying to?

Comment: I'll take a look at the documentation for it over the weekend and give you a few ideas (but you definitely need to change you controller code to return a view model)